# What does java.io.File.length() return for a directory?

Tags: java, file, file-io

The javadoc for java.io.File.length() states:

> Returns the length of the file denoted by this abstract pathname. The return value is unspecified if this pathname denotes a directory.

I've been testing on Solaris which seems to be based on the number of files in the directory, but it always returns a greater number than there are files\folders including '.' files.

Does anyone know what this value means on Solaris\Linux\OSX\Windows? It's probably OS specific but it would be good to know if it has any value at all!

**EDIT:**

I agree with the comments which have advised that this is not a feature which should be used for the "Write Once, Run Anywhere" Java methodology, however since the value returned is not 0L (which it might be on some OS's but not Solaris) i'm interested in knowing what the value does refer to.

The native Java calls are usually direct single OS procedures so whatever the value refers to has some meaning and you get it for free without needing to load more java.io.File(s).

Comment: It would be OS dependant but I would expect it to return the space used on disk. BTW: The directory is a special type of file with the names and nodes in the directory. If you are root on UNIX you can read the bytes of the directory like it was a file.

Comment: The JavaDoc for java.io.File says it's unspecified for directories. The JavaDoc for the abstract class java.io.FileSystem (which is what File.length() calls) says it's defined to be zero fro directories. It's actually implemented in native code, which I don't know how to look at. Anyway, if it's non-zero, the native code is against the spec of java.io.Filesystem.

Comment: It returns the number of developers who actually know what the number means =P. Anyway, that number is something you shouldn't rely on, since the javadocs says it is unspecified.

Comment: Here is the answer: "The return value is unspecified if this pathname denotes a directory"

Answer (score 2):

File.length is mostly used to determine the size of a file. It should never be used to determine the number of files in diretory.  The fact that the JavaDocs state that's undefined should have triggered warning bells.

If you won't to know the number of files in a directory, you should use [File.listFiles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) instead (or one of its alternatives)